# Roots of $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

How can I go on to show that the roots of $1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n$ are exactly

$$\exp\left(\frac{2ki\pi}{n+1}\right)$$

for $k=1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: Multiply by $x-1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(1-x)(1+x+x^{2}+...+x^{n})= 1-x^{n+1}$. So the roots are same as the roots of $1-x^{n+1}=0$ except for $x=1$.